# Is it possible to filter/block all international sellers while searching on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I've had some bad experiences with international sellers on Amazon. They fall into two categories:

- **Shipping time**: It took ages until the product arrived (sometimes more than 6 weeks; mostly sellers from China)
- **Quality / Return conditions**: Something was not ok with the product and I needed to return it. Then it was more expensive to return it than the products cost (mostly sellers from the UK).

When searching for products, I would like to restrict the search to sellers who are in Germany. Is that possible with Amazon.de?